# Setting focus to a UITextField without using becomeFirstResponder()

Tags: swift, xcode

Is there any way of making a `UITextField` selected by default without using `becomeFirstResponder()`. The method `becomeFirstResponder()` automatically scrolls my `UIScrollView` so that the `UITextField` is at the top of the page, which i don't want.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to  disable scrolling of the scrollview before calling `becomeFirstResponder`, re-enabling it afterwards:

```
scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
[textField becomeFirstResponder];
scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
```

*However, be careful with not wanting this scrolling behavior as it might be useful on smaller screens to reveal the text field.*

Comment: If you really want to force it, you can put a timer of 0 seconds to enable it again. This 'hack' ensures it is called after drawing.

Comment: Can you try saving the `scrollView.contentOffset` in a variable before calling `becomeFirstResponder`, and then restoring it afterwards: `scrollView.contentOffset = …`